# .net Maui Launcher.OpenAsync not working for iOS(simulator)

Tags: c#, ios, maui, tel

I'm writing an iOS/Android app that has clickable telephone links.

My code for clicking on a link looks like this:

```
Label lblPhoneLine = new Label() { Text = "(000) 00-00000" };
lblPhoneLink.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
{
  Command = new Command(async () =>
  {
    await Launcher.OpenAsync("tel:000-00-0000");
  })
});
stackLayout.Add(lblPhone);
```

This code works fine for Android devices, but for iOS it doesn't do anything.
Also I've tried `PhoneDialer.Open` and that doesn't work either for iOS.  Also removing the dashes in the phone number doesn't work either.
Any ideas or workarounds?

Also if this helps I am using the iPhone 15 iOS 17.2 Simulator.
Thanks

Comment: The iOS simulator does not have a phone app

Comment: It will never work on a Simulator because the app does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Application list from iOS simulator, it does not support the phone App.
[image]

It is recommand to achieve the function by deploying the project to iPhone device with [Automatic provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vs) or [Manual provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vs).